# php paypal pro (advanced) integration Issue

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am new to paypal integration.I want to integrate paypal pro (advanced) in my website.I dont know Vendor,User,Partner and password.I have tried my paypal username and password but it does not work.Kindly help me how to get Vendor,User,Partner IDs.I want to use sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want PayPal PRO, I would suggest you to go for `PayPal Payments PRO` (PayPal is processor),
or if you want to use a different processor you can go for `Payflow PRO` or `Payflow link`.

For PayPal Payments PRO, signup for new business account at `developer.paypal.com`->upgrade it for PRO.

For Payflow PRO/link, singup at `manager.paypal.com`. You will get the Vendor,User and Partner IDs.